# What is the tighest known bound for Hensel lifting?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am lifting factorizations $U(x)=V(x)W(x)$ mod $p$ to a factorization mod $p^k$ such that if there's a factorization in of $U(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we find it. At the moment I'm ensuring $p^k > \|U\|_2 \binom{d}{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$ where $d$ is the degree of $U(x)$. I believe this is a version of Mignotte's bound.

I was wondering if tighter bounds have been found so I can reduce the number of iterations needed to lift solutions, and indeed if this bound is always correct.